# What is the difference between ADT and collection?

Tags: java

I have the definitons for both on my textbook as:

ADT: a specification for a group of values and the operations on those values 
     that are defined conceptually and independently from any programming 
     language.

collection: An object that groups other objects and provides vaious services to
            its client.

Also, the book specifies that a collection is an ADT but an ADT is not necessarily a collection.

Get a little confused about the two concepts. Anyone can give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: A collection is a data type that holds multiple values of some kind of data.  E.g. an array, list, or set.

Comment: "the book specifies that a collection is an ADT but an ADT is not necessarily a collection" A dog is an animal, but an animal is not always a dog. A collection is just one type of ADT.

Comment: Any example of ADT which is not a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to put it so its easy to understand as I remember when I was learning about it that it took me a few times.

An ADT, or Abstract Data Type, specifies (you guessed it) the data type. It defines what the data type holds (`int`, `string`, custom values etc.), what it can do (the operations and methods that can be performed on and with them) and how it behaves (what happens and what it does as a result of something else e.g. when created, do this).

A collection is an object that can hold many other objects. For example, a `map` is a collection which holds pairs. Each pair has a `key` and a `value`. You can even nest a collection here such as the `key` being (but not limited to) an `int` or a `string` and the `value` could then be a `list`.

A `list` is essentially an `array` although more advanced and flexible. Lists can have multiple occurrences (or duplicates) such as having the `string` `'test'` appear three times. The elements follow a specific order which can be searched. New elements can be placed at a position you specify too.

The `map` and `list` are just two examples of collections and you could see more in the Java `Collections` framework.

Hope this answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

Only the behaviour is defined in ADT (Abstract Data Type) whereas a Collection is a Abstract Data Type for groupling multiple values together.

The implementation of ADTs are Concrete Data Type (CDT)

Example :

Stack,Queue are ADTs where only the behaviour is defined and not the implementations.

Set,List are collections where we group multiple objects together.

So you use Collections to achieve the tasks of ADTs. Like we use a Array to implement behaviour of Stack.